# Flutter keyboard over textfield on physical device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I run the app on ios simulator or android emulator, there's no problem about keyboard, everything works fine. But when I run on the physical device by testflight, keyboard displaying over SendInputField. Can't see input field and send button.

Here is the code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBarWidget(
         
        ),
        body: _mainBody(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  _mainBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              reverse: true,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  _buildList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 0,
            child: Obx(() => Visibility(
                visible: controller.isLoading.value,
                child: const CustomLoadingAPI())),
          ),
          Expanded(flex: 0, child: _submitButton(context)),
          SizedBox(height: Dimensions.heightSize)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _submitButton(BuildContext context) {

    return Align(
      ....
          SendInputField(
            
            hintText: Strings.typeYour.tr,
            onTap: () {
              if (!LocalStorage.isFreeUser()) {
                if (controller.chatController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  controller.proccessChat(args[0]);
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50))
                      .then((_) => controller.scrollDown());
                } else {
                  ToastMessage.error(Strings.writeSomethingg.tr);
                }
              } else {
                ...
              }
            },
           ,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildList() {
    return Obx(() => ListView.builder(
          controller: controller.scrollController,
          itemCount: controller.itemCount.value,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ChatMessageWidget(
                ....
                text: controller.messages.value[index].text,
              ...
                index: index);
          },
        ));
  }

}
```

Any suggestion? How should I fix this problem?

Comment: try to move the `SingleChildScrollView` out, above the first column in `_mainBody`

Comment: and one tip, use widgets instead of functions

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the bug, do you have other template code too?

Comment: As I checked, the key is simulator / physical device difference about the bug. There's no problem about this page, no problem in the simulator, the problem in the physical device. Is there any option on flutter configurations about debug/release difference or something? @Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can use bottom insets like this:

```
_mainBody(BuildContext context) {
  return Obx(
    () => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), // <- add bottom padding
      child: Column(
        // your existing code
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: not working, sorry

Answer (score -1):

SingleChildScrollView. This ensures that the content is scrollable when the keyboard appears, allowing users to access the TextField even when the keyboard is on the screen.

```
        class MyForm extends StatelessWidget {
            @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                    // Your other widgets can go here
                    Text('Other Widgets'),
                    TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your text'),
                    ),
                    // More widgets
                    ],
                ),
                ),
            );
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried SingleChildScrollView. It works on simulator, not again in physical device. As I checked, the key is simulator / physical device difference about the bug. There's no problem about this page, no problem in the simulator, the problem in the physical device. Is there any option on flutter configurations about debug/release difference or something?

Comment: If you're using text fields within the SingleChildScrollView, ensure that you're handling the keyboard properly using the ListView or SingleChildScrollView properties like keyboardDismissBehavior and keyboardVerticalOffset.